# NuGetter failing to create directory on a hosted TFS server

Tags: tfs, nuget, nugetter

I'm trying to use [NuGetter](http://nugetter.codeplex.com/) to create a NuGet package in a hosted build server on tfs.VisualStudio.com.   My understanding is that it fails as soon as the tool tries to create a new folder to use as the staging ground for the packaging process.  This is the error I get:

> ```
> Exception Message: Access to the path '$/main/Drops/MyBuild/MyBuild_20130128.4\NuGetPackage' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)
> Exception Stack Trace:    
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
> at TfsBuild.NuGetter.Activities.CreateFolder.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) in c:\Users\svc-tauintbuilder\Downloads\Source\TfsBuild.NuGetter.Activities\CreateFolder.cs:line 53   
> at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
> at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
> ```

The project is open source so I took a look at the code in that area and it is indeed just a simple call to `Directory.CreateDirectory`:

```
public string DoCreateFolder(string dropLocation, string folderName)
{
    string folderToCreate;

    if (Path.IsPathRooted(folderName))
    {
        folderToCreate = folderName;
    }
    else
    {
        folderToCreate = Path.Combine(dropLocation, folderName);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderToCreate))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderToCreate);
    }

    return folderToCreate;
}
```

I'm a neophyte when it comes to TFS, hosted or not. Is there anything I can do to get around this issue?

Comment: you can open an issue on nugetter http://nugetter.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic to see if there  is something that could be done here.

Comment: There's already a recent discussion of the issue here:  http://nugetter.codeplex.com/discussions/429967 and I have reached out to the maintainer.  I guess what I'm really asking is whether or not I should reasonably expect to be able to create a new folder on a hosted build server.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the method signature and the file path in the error ($/main/Drops...)   I'm guessing this would be reproducible using on-prem TFS where you configure the build to be archived to source control.  The Directory class isn't going to understand what $/ refers to.  It seems that it would need to be passed BinariesRoot or similar instead and then let TFS pick everything up and check it in.